# Generalized Additive Modeling Apache Spark implementation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Does Spark MLlib support Generalized Additive Modeling? How does one go about implementing GAM models in Spark?
I want to implement GAM (Generalized additive model) model in Spark. Based on my research on online forums, I could not find the implementation of GAM models on Spark. Has anyone in this community attempted this? Does Spark MLlib support GAM?

https://reposit.haw-hamburg.de/bitstream/20.500.12738/7778/1/BachelorarbeitKaiBrusch.pdf
This document shows how to manipulate GLM on Spark MLlib but does not have the actual GAM on Spark implementation.

Comment: I have not done this specific example. Spark can use many Python libraries. Did you try to install PyGAM or statsmodels?  You would need to convert the Spark dataframe to a pandas dataframe or numpy array before calling those libraries. That would take up the memory on the Spark controller and the work of training the GAM would not leverage Spark. But if Spark is the platform you must use and you data can fit onto 1 machine this may work.

Comment: We have to use Spark for the scale we are dealing with. We are trying this with pandas UDF at the moment have made some progress. I will post here if we are able to solve this issue.